# Generate Enum from Values present in a table using ADO.NET Entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, enums, t4

My requirement is to create an Enum based on values present in a table from DB. I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework model (.edmx file), Can any one of you help me out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is probably a lot easier to use T4 templates. [Here is a really good article on getting started](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)

My example below uses a direct SQL Connection, but as you can see you can include any code and generate whatever output you like into a cs file that is compiled into your project. You could replace the ADO syntax below with an enumeration over a collection of objects retrieved via your Entituy Framework model and output accordingly.

Create a file with the extension .tt in the directory where you would like the enumeration file to be generated. If you name the file XXXXX.tt then a file called XXXXX.cs will be generated so, name the tt file appropriately.

Try something along these lines. You might need to experiment a little with the syntax and the output, but I'm not going to write it all for you or you won't learn anything :)

Just be aware, that this database call will be made every time you edit the tt file.

```
<#@ template language="C#" hostspecific="True" debug="True" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" #>
<#
    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX; Integrated Security=True");
    sqlConn.Open();
#>
namespace AppropriateNamespace
{
public enum YourEnumName
{
    <#
    string sql = string.Format("SELECT Id, Name FROM YourTable ORDER BY Id");
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConn);
    IDataReader reader = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();

    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        sb.Append(FixName(reader["Name"].ToString()) + " = " + reader["Id"] + "," + Environment.NewLine + "\t\t");
    }
    reader.Close();
    sqlComm.Dispose();
    #>
<#= sb.ToString() #>
    }
}
```

Try improving on this. Rather than writing to a StringBuilder, output the results of each reader.Read() directly to the output. Also, I have included a FixName method that doesn't exist yet, but you might need that to take out spaces or illegal characters.

Comment: I am currently looking for a helpful link

Comment: Let me know how you get on. I will Edit my answer based on your feedback to make it more helpful to others

Comment: Good to hear. Would you be able to tag your question with the T4 tag?

Answer (score 7):

Daniel's template is nice and all, but I've put some more effort into [such a template](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html) so it does all these:

- generates enumeration values with explicit integer values;
- uses Visual Studio's namespace naming convention so generated enumerations have project's default namespace with any subfolders appended (just like any code file in Visual Studio);
- adds complete enumeration XML documentation by using additional description table column values; if you don't have these never mind;
- correctly names the generated file and adds an additional attribute in the code so the generated `enum` doesn't get scrutinised by code analysis;
- multi-word lookup table values are correctly concatenated to pascal-cased equivalents (ie. *Multi word value* becomes a `MultiWordValue`);
- enumeration values always start with a letter;
- all enumeration values consist of only letters and numbers, everything else gets cut out;

Anyway. Everything is very well documented in [this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/generate-enum-of-database-lookup-table.html).