# Entity Framework Enum and string association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to use the method in [this article](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/associating-strings-with-enums-in-c) to implement friendlier ToString() outputs for my enum types. I would like to know how this can be done in Entity Framework's auto generated Enum codes? Would I have to modify the code generation template (if so, can someone kindly give me some guidance since the template is rather complicated), or can someone suggest an alternative method?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "auto generated Enum codes"? Are you talking about using "model/DB first" approach?

Comment: This covers enum support for EF Database first approach:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731557/enum-support-for-entity-framework-database-first  Take a look at the alternative answers as well for additional links.

Comment: @Floremin: Yes I'm using model first. So my entire model is done via the designer, including my enum types. The classes which contain the enum declarations are therefore auto-generated by EF's T4. Now the problem is that my enum's are hard to use in my ASP.net website due to the restricted naming of the enum type, the scenario described exactly in the article I linked, in which the author used DescriptionAttribute (reflection) to work around the issue. I don't think this can be done in EF though without extensive modification to the T4 template, since the code is auto generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use your own enum type in your EF model, instead of creating a new enum in the model designer. Here's how:

In the model designer, rght click on surface and select:

**Add New -> Enum Type...**

In the dialog, just set checkbox:

**Reference external type**

and enter your type: `namespace.MyEnum`

Then create columns in your tables to use this type.

Since you're likely going to modify the existing model, make sure there is no confusion between enum type from the model and (external) enum type from your code. Best approach would be to remove the enum type you previously had created in the model and adjust the columns to use the associated enum type from your code.

Now, you can declare your enum type with description attributes as you planned.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the external reference option that I've always overlooked. I tried this and it seems to work perfectly. EF's designer still has access to the new enum types this way, which means they can easily be used as property types for my entities (no need to manually set anything on the database). I'm very satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to make workarounds for enums. They're supported in the latest Entity Framework.

To make your enums friendly to your website you can use attributes. Here is sample attribute:

```
public class EnumDescription : Attribute
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public EnumDescription(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}
```

Mark your enums with attribute:

```
public enum DaylightSavingTime
{
    [EnumDescription("Detect automatically")]
    Auto = 0,
    [EnumDescription("DST always on")]
    AlwaysOn = 1,
    [EnumDescription("DST always off")]
    AlwaysOff = 2
}
```

Add extensions to enable `ToDescription()` method:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToDescription(this Enum enumeration)
    {
        Type type = enumeration.GetType();
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(enumeration.ToString());

        if (null != memInfo && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDescription), false);
            if (null != attrs && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((EnumDescription)attrs[0]).Text;
        }

        return enumeration.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var blabla = DaylightSavingTime.Auto;
Console.WriteLine(blabla.ToDescription());
```

Output:

*Detect automatically*

Comment: Yes I understand it's supported and I'm already using it. My problem is that due to the naming restriction of enum (for example, a member can only be named NewYork, not New York), my enum types are difficult to use in my asp.net website (as described in that article I linked).

Comment: @user3144721, I've updated the answer (If you like it, vote up)

Comment: Appreciate your response, though I did link the article that describes this (using attribute for friendly enum name) in my original post. My problem was that using EF's model designer, the enums declarations are auto-generated and non-editable (any modification to auto generated class files will be overwritten anytime the model is updated), and therefore I cannot add the attributes. Floremin's method (writing enums externally) seems to be my only choice if I want to accomplish this at design time.

Comment: I also realized that the extension method approach you proposed is a great idea (instead of using a regular static method shown in the article I read, which I was going to follow). Now I will use the extension method in the externally defined enum types. Best of both worlds. Thank you!