# Entity Framework Code First Enumerations

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have an Entity Framework CodeFirst model that I'm creating from existing Database and I want to decorate some Enumerations types that are defined in Database.

For example I have a column called type which is an enum('INPUT', 'OUTPUT'). It's possible to define this by using decorations in the class properties?

I have seen that it's possible to use [EnumType] decoration but in C# string enumerations are not supported.

Comment: I think that your question is answered (here)[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj248772.aspx].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enum Support for Entity Framework Database First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731557/enum-support-for-entity-framework-database-first)